# Install X11 version of Firefox on OSX 10.8.2

Tags: macos, firefox, x11

I'm trying to install a x11-enabled version of Firefox on my OSX 10.8.2, so it can integrate nicely with xmonad.

My problem: Firefox in macports is extremely old (7.x) and building 17.x from source fails with some cryptic error:

```
/Users/wherr/Downloads/mozilla-release/_virtualenv/bin/python ../../config/pythonpath.py -I../../config ../../config/expandlibs_gen.py --depend .deps/libi18n.a.desc.pp -o libi18n.a.desc nsI18nModule.o  ../lwbrk/src/liblwbrk_s.a ../unicharutil/src/libucharucomp_s.a ../strres/src/libstrres_s.a ../locale/src/libnslocale_s.a ../locale/src/mac/libplatlocale_s.a ../hyphenation/src//libhyphenation_s.a 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../../config/pythonpath.py", line 56, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "../../config/pythonpath.py", line 48, in main
    execfile(script, frozenglobals)
  File "../../config/expandlibs_gen.py", line 43, in <module>
    print >>outfile, generate(args)
  File "../../config/expandlibs_gen.py", line 27, in generate
    raise Exception("File not found: %s" % arg)
Exception: File not found: ../locale/src/mac/libplatlocale_s.a
```

Any idea what can I try now to get firefox working with x11?

I'm using the same configure switches as firefox-x11 from macports, namely:

```
./configure --enable-default-toolkit=cairo-gtk2  \
--with-xulrunner-stub-name=xulrunner-stub --disable-static \
--enable-shared --disable-official-branding --with-branding=browser/branding/unofficial \
--with-distribution-id=org.macports --enable-default-toolkit=cairo-gtk2 \
--enable-libxul --disable-system-lcms --disable-system-cairo \
--disable-system-sqlite --enable-oji --enable-plugins \
--enable-mathml --enable-extensions="default,spellcheck" \
--enable-permissions --enable-cookie \ 
--enable-image-decoders=all --enable-image-encoder=all --enable-canvas --enable-jsd \
--disable-xpctools --enable-crypto --enable-pango --enable-svg \
--enable-svg-renderer=cairo --enable-xinerama --with-pthreads \
--disable-gnomevfs --disable-gnomeui --enable-postscript --enable-safe-browsing \
--disable-crashreporter --enable-optimize='-O2' \
--disable-prebinding --enable-strip --enable-install-strip \
--disable-debug --disable-installer --disable-updater --disable-pedantic \
--disable-tests --disable-mochitest --disable-necko-wifi --enable-llvm-hacks
```

The complete config.log is available here: http://knping.org/~herself/config.log. After the configure I proceed with typing `gmake`.

Comment: Could you please provide *how* you compiled it? Arguments to the configure script and so on?

Comment: Okay, updated the post.

Comment: Not what you asked, but as an easy alternative you could install your favorite Linux in VirtualBox and use seamless mode. If you haven't used virtualization, you might be surprised how well it works.

Comment: The last one in fink is firefox 8 from 2011.  It runs, but I can't get it to do much of anything on jira.  I'm trying to do a similar thing so I don't have to switch between my normal X11-based desktop and firefox all the time.  Using the normal OSX firefox isn't difficult, it's just the principle of the thing.  This /should/ be possible...

Answer (score -3):

It doesn't matter.  X11 is no longer available, it was completely removed from the Mac OS after Snow Leopard.

Best bet is to run an older version under a virtual machine.

Comment: Not the entire truth.

Comment: Crap, youa re right, I totally forgot that they added some functionality back in 10.7.

Comment: What about xquartz?

Comment: You can still get X11, which Apple does support under Mountain Lion. Apple does not install as default because not enough people use it, and it is regularly updated, Apple never got the time to provide the update through MAS.

Comment: Xquartz installs with almost a single click in 10.11 (el capitan).  Runs like a champ.  Best to get your facts straight before mouthing off.